# how to activated new function after button clicked for three times

Tags: javascript, function, dom

i want to add new function after i clicked the button 3 times and erase/remove the former function

html file:

```
<body> 
  <div id="background">
    <p>this background white, before</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn-1">change color</button>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
const btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn-1") ;
const bg = document.getElementById("background")

const toRed = ()=>{
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
const toBlue = ()=>{
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "steelblue";
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', toRed);
```

// i want this **btn1** have function to clear function **toRed** and add **toBlue** instead after clicked 3 times

Comment: Do you need to "erase" the function or just want to run the `toBlue` function to change the colour to blue?

Comment: @Esszed i want erase too if it possible or kinda deactivated it and pass the new function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the event listener and add a new one when it was clicked three times:

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn-1");
const bg = document.getElementById("background");
var redClicked = 0;
const toRed = ()=>{
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  redClicked++;
  if (redClicked >= 3) {
    btn1.removeEventListener('click', toRed);
    btn1.addEventListener('click', toBlue);
  }
}
const toBlue = ()=>{
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "steelblue";
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', toRed);
```

```html
<body> 
  <div id="background">
    <p>this background white, before</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn-1">change color</button>
</body>
```